# Is there any way to create a DbCompiledModel without having EF load provider information from the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'd like to construct an EF DbCompiledModel from a DbModelBuilder without actually connecting to a database. Is there any way to do this? It looks like I can build a model using a DbProviderInfo, but I don't know how to get a providerInvariantName & providerManifestToken.

The reason I would like to do this is that I want to leverage the EF to SQL compiler offline to generate some queries without having access to the database. I'm using EF 5.

Comment: What database are you trying to create the SQL for?

Comment: @Pawel SqlServer 2008

Comment: you can use "System.Data.SqlClient" as the provider invariant name and "2008" as the provider manifest token.

Comment: @Pawel: this seems to work. If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SqlServer the provider invariant name is "System.Data.SqlClient" and the provider manifest tokens are "2005" for SqlServer 2005, "2008" for SqlServer 2008. In EF6 there are also "2012" for SqlServer 2012 and "2012.Azure" for Azure.